# Fetch Assoc Grouping Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following SQL query to pull in data from my 'worksheetdata' table. Using this query, the following data is returned...

```
id         date         sportsbook         bet         to_win         status
1          2013-07-05   bu                 1000.00     1200.00        1
2          2013-07-05   bm                 1500.00     238.94         2
3          2013-07-05   bm                 100.00      55.00          1
4          2013-07-06   bm                 2000.00     1850.57        1
5          2013-07-06   5d                 280.00      127.85         2
```

I already have PHP in place which adds values together to come up with a "running total" for the bets. Dependant on the status, it adds the value from either bet or to_win appropriately to an array, and then I use the sum of the array later on. For a small example, see below...

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

    if($row["status"] === '1') {
        $total[] = $row["to_win"];
    }

    if($row["status"] === '2') {
        $total[] = '-' . $row["bet"];
    }

}

echo 'Running Total (Lifetime): ' . array_sum($total);
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is using the same logic above, I'd like to get the running total for each date and each sportsbook respectively. I'd like to then insert that into a database table for later reference, but the INSERT query is simple enough. Finally, I have my question...

1. What would be the best way to go about getting the data grouped together by date & sportsbook using the PHP above? I know that I could do something like this...

   ```
    if($row["sportsbook"] == 'bu') {

     if($row["status"] === '1') {
         $total[] = $row["to_win"];
     }

     if($row["status"] === '2') {
         $total[] = '-' . $row["bet"];
     }

    }
   ```

... Though this wouldn't address the date bit (I'd have to add another clause for date, and this just seems clunky).

Comment: I know the question is asking about PHP but is it feasible for you to do your grouping in another SQL statement? It would be fairly simple and less error prone. You could even do your running sum in MySQL if you wanted.

Comment: I advise against what you are trying to do. If in the future your 'status' or 'sportsbook' categories grow larger, you will need more and more code.